# Managed Bean with more than one scope

Tags: java, jsf, request, managed-bean, session-scope

I have a simple question for you experts

Is it possible to have both a Session-Scoped and Request-Scoped for the same bean?

For example, i have a bean `myBean`, can it be both `Session-Scoped` and `Request-Scoped`?

**EDIT**

After doing some trials, i decided to destroy the first session which is session scoped.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().remove("SessionBean1");
```

is there a way i can re-initialise it to a request scoped one?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to define a bean of the same type in two different scopes by [defining it in a `faces-config.xml` file](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSFIntro5.html#wp114997). This will result in two different instances when referenced through expressions like `#{sessionScope.myBean}`, `#{requestScope.myBean}`, etc.

It is possible to place the same bean instance into more than one scope programmatically using the [`FacesContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html).

However, the presence of such beans suggests a design flaw.

Comment: so its better to have two beans?

Comment: Hard to say. You have at least definitely a serious flaw in the design.

Comment: @BalusC any way to set the bean to request scoped after destroying the session bean by using the facescontext?

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate a managed bean with more than one scope. The code will compile and deploy without errors (tested with Mojarra 2.1.3 / Glassfish 3.1.1).

However, the effect will be that always the most narrow scope will be applied. So if you annotate your bean with `@SessionScoped` and `@RequestScoped`, the bean will be in request scope.